# PHP preg_match_all strings starting with C and length of 4

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm attempting to search a text document with a PHP script and return all strings that start with the character "C" and have a length of 4.  Some of the results will end in "=" but most will end in an alphanumeric character.

I was able to to successfully pull the ones that started with C and ended in =.

```html
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('./FILENAME.txt', true);
preg_match_all('/C(.{2,3})=/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
foreach ($matches[0] as $sub)
{
$file = './CapturedData.txt';
file_put_contents($file, print_r("\"".$sub . "\"\n", true), FILE_APPEND); 
}
?>
```

but when I tried to adjust it to pull all strings starting with C and ending in any alphanumeric character and being the length of 3/4, it just returns the first 3/4 characters out of ANY length strings.

I know I'm missing something simple, but its killing me.   Anything I try just keeps returning the first x characters out of any length string.  While I only want to return strings that have a length of 3/4, starting with "C" and ending in =,a-z,A-Z,0-9

EDIT:
Lets say these are the strings in the document:

```
blahblahblahCaa=
Cae=
CGGG
dontmatchthisCAAA
CAAAjkjkjk
XXXXXXCXXXX
```

I only want to return the 2nd and 3rd line

Comment: an example would be better. What's wrong with `C(.{2,3})[a-zA-Z0-9](?!\S)`

Comment: Is the  total length of string including `=` is four or you want to exclude the `=` from the count?

Comment: The above returns strings that end in "C"xxx, so it returns a value from the string: "XXXXXXXCXXX", while I only want it to return values where C is the first character

Comment: The strings that I'm trying to return are as follows
CAE= or CMgB

Comment: could you explain clearly what the `X` in this string `"XXXXXXXCXXX"` means?

Comment: Lets say these are the strings in the document:
blahblahblahCaa=
Cae=
CGGG
dontmatchthisCAAA
CAAAjkjkjk
XXXXXXCXXXX

I only want to return the 2nd and 3rd line

Comment: @vv0si could you provide the above comment in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need to provide anchors to do an exact line match.

```
^C(?:\S{2,3})[a-zA-Z0-9=]$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wT0zZ8/2)

```
$input = <<<EOT
blahblahblahCaa=
Cae=
CGGG
dontmatchthisCAAA
CAAAjkjkjk
XXXXXXCXXXX
EOT;
preg_match_all("~^C(?:\S{2,3})[a-zA-Z0-9=]$~m", $input, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cae=
            [1] => CGGG
        )

)
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
C                        'C'
(?:                      group, but do not capture:
  \S{2,3}                  non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (between 2 and 3 times)
)                        end of grouping
[a-zA-Z0-9=]             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                         '0' to '9', '='
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Answer (score 0):

the comment above alludes to it -- your regex does not specify that the string has to end at the ending character, just that it has to contain it.  So Caaaa matches, but so does Caaaabbb and so would Caaa=bbb.  You don't say what your input format is, but if it's one word per line, you can match /^C(..|...)[a-zA-Z0-9=]$/m

Answer (score 0):

From what i understands,

```
\bC\S{2,3}=?(?=\s)
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/lR6kI3/3

- `C` matches a `C`
- `\S{2,3}` matches anything other than a space. `{2,3}` quantifies the regex 2 or 3 times
- `=?` optional `=`
- `(?=\s)` checks if the string is followed by space

Example usage

```
$re = "/\\bC\\S{2,3}=?(?=\\s)/m"; 
$str = "blahblahblahCaa= Cae= CGGG dontmatchthisCAAA CAAAjkjkjk XXXXXXCXXXX "; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Will give an output as

```
Array ( [0] => Cae= [1] => CGGG )
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
    $str = file_get_contents('FILENAME.txt', true);
   // $str = "blahblahblahCaa=\nCae=\nCGGG\ndontmatchthisCAAA\nCAAAjkjkjk\nXXXXXXCXXXX"; 
        preg_match_all('/^C[a-zA-Z0-9=]{3}$/m', $str, $matches);
        var_dump($matches[0]);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $sub)
        {
            $file = 'CapturedData.txt';
            file_put_contents($file, $sub, FILE_APPEND);    
        }
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wT0zZ8/3)